# Run Procedure on File Import

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a procedure which selects data from a table called Test. And the way the data is loaded into the test Table is through File Import.

What I am trying is, Is there a way to run the Procedure automatically whenever there is an import on the Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSIS, you can add an execute SQl task to runthe proc after the main import work. We do this in all our import pacakges to save meta data. If you are running the import from a job, an alternative would be to use a second task in the job to run your proc.

Comment: I am using a third party tool called i/o tool to do the File Import

Answer (score -1):

You can have a trigger on the Insert but that would work on a row by row basis

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: No triggers do not work on a row-by-row basis but on a batch basis.

Comment: The OP wants "run the Procedure automatically whenever there is an import on the Table" so an after insert trigger would work to fire off the procedure, so I agree with @Phil on the trigger and with @HLEGM on the row by row